# PXE Boot End Up In Dracut Command Line

Tags: boot, pxe

I've deployed a pxe boot environment on CentOS7, with classic syslinux & tftp-server glued up together.

I'm using a mac specific file for menu from /var/lib/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/ directory. and the menu has following options

label Manual
    menu label Manual Installation
    kernel vmlinuz
    append initrd=initrd.img ip=dhcp repo=ftp://192.168.0.254/pub/C7

Now It Proceeds like this.

1. New Machine boots from network & gets an IP from DHCP.
2. It Shows PXE Menu.
3. When press enter on menu, it loads kernel & initrd.
4. then shows plenty of output, till it enters into dracut commandline mood.

Now I have no idea, why it's happening & how to get through this. If someone has experienced it, and can help, it would be such a great guidance.
[image]

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I faced the same thing, my question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516651/cant-start-vm-with-pxe-write-error-no-space-left-on-device-and-end-up-in-dra

Comment: @Dmitry no my friend, at least not in a test vm, but could work in on a live server, not sure tho